# Finding suitable local defining functions for hypersurfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}^{m},m\geq 2$ and $\mathcal{Z}$ be an analytic submanifold of codimension $2$. Also, suppose $\mathcal{Z}=\mathcal{Z}_{1}\cap\mathcal{Z}_{2}$, where $\mathcal{Z}_{i}$ is an analytic hypersurface in $\Omega$ for $i=1,2$. Now, fix $p\in\mathcal{Z}$.

Is it possible to choose local defining functions $\phi_{i}$ for $\mathcal{Z}_{i},~i=1,2$ at $p$ such that $p$ is also a regular point for the $\mathbb{C}^{2}$-valued function $(\phi_{1},\phi_{2})?$

Comment: What if $p$ is a singular point of one or both hypersurfaces?

Comment: For a submanifold $\mathcal{Z}$ of codimension r, there exists a $\mathbb{C}^{r}$ valued submersion around $p$(say $U_{p}$) s.t. $U_{p}\cap\mathcal{Z}$ is its zero set. This makes $p$ a regular point of the newly defined function. If $r=1$, the submersion would be a local defining function for $\mathcal{Z}$ at $p$(a power series argument is needed for this conclusion).

Comment: Sorry — I was thinking about analytic subvarieties as opposed to submanifolds. So your issue boils down to whether the two hypersurfaces meet transversely at $p$ or not. Consider $p=0$ in $y=y-x^2=0$. (Here you can see that you have a non-reduced scheme for $\mathcal Z$.)

Comment: Got it. Thanks.